# Error when running code through command line

Tags: java, init

I have this code:

```
public class PlayGame
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PlayGame p = new PlayGame();
    p.startup();
}


PlayGame p = new PlayGame();
GameLogic g = new GameLogic();
```

(With correct formatting). The startup class just has some code which I know works fine. Its just printing out stuff. However when running I get a load of errors

```
at PlayGame.<init>(PlayGame.java:13)
```

This is repeated a lot and is the only thing I see in command line.
I have found by inserting

```
System.exit(0)
```

between lines to exit before the error appears that it is in the

```
PlayGame p = new PlayGame();
```

line. I have no idea why it is so any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: what errors do you encounter?

Comment: Don't remove the line from your question. People won't know where the error came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PlayGame` class has an instance field

```
PlayGame p = new PlayGame();
```

So each `PlayGame` object creates a `PlayGame` object, which creates a `PlayGame` object, ad nauseam.

You'll eventually run out of memory with a `StackOverflowError`.

**Why do you need an instance of `PlayGame` within an instance of `PlayGame`?**

Comment: Thanks, it was how I originally had it. I've now deleted PlayGame outside the static void main(String[] args). The once inside that is to start the method. Is that needed or can I also remove that one?

Comment: @pokeairguy Ideally (separation of concerns) you would have your `main` method in some other dedicated class.

Comment: @Soltirios Delimanolis I have a total of 3 classes which link together. The playGame is the first one which links to the other 2. So I have the main method there to start it of

Comment: @pokeairguy It will work fine. However, read about [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), an important pattern in software design. Your `PlayGame` should contain the behavior for playing the game. A `main` method is the entry point of a Java application. It is unrelated to your `PlayGame` class. It should probably be a completely separate class that has the purpose of launching your application.

Comment: @Soltirios Delimanolis Thanks. This is for some coursework and its how we've been told to lay it out I believe. However the error is still occuring. Please see my revised question for how my code looks now. Am I still making the same mistake?

Comment: @pokeairguy When changing your code, add it as an edit below your question. Otherwise there's no trace to what you've done. Also, **post the error**.

Comment: I thought that was what I had done, shall try and do that next time then. The error is: (Without the '')
'at GameLogic.<init>(GameLogic.java:6)'
This goes all the way through command line

Comment: @pokeairguy Does your `GameLogic` class also have a `GameLogic` field?

Comment: It had GameLogic g = new GameLogic(); like PlayGame did. I have now removed that and altered the code to fit accordinaly and its all working now. Thanks very much for your help, much appreciated